# Normal force acting not on the center

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

I have a question about normal force:

How do you find it's magnitude when there is just on contact point betwenn bodies and not directly below the center of the mass? For example, how would one calculate normal force and friction in situation like this one the picture?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Normal force in the picture not perpendicular to the surface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543952/why-is-the-normal-force-in-the-picture-not-perpendicular-to-the-surface)

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

First, identify the degrees of freedom in order to account for all unknowns. In this case, it is $x$ and $\alpha$ and together with the unknown normal $N$ are the **3** unknowns to be solved for by the **3** equations of motion.

First, you need the kinematics of the center of mass, as a function of $x$ and $\alpha$. I designate time derivatives with a dot $\dot \square$ or $\ddot \square$ for the 2nd derivative.

Once you have the components of acceleration of the center of mass (along this axis of the body) as a function of the degrees of freedom and their derivatives

$$\boldsymbol{a}_{\rm CM} = \pmatrix{ a_x(x,\alpha,\dot x, \dot \alpha, \ddot x, \ddot \alpha) \\ a_y(x,\alpha,\dot x, \dot \alpha, \ddot x, \ddot \alpha)}$$

then you formulate the equations of motion (along this axis of the body)

$$ \pmatrix{m g \sin \alpha \\ -m g \cos \alpha} + \pmatrix{-\mu N \\ N } = m \,\boldsymbol{a}_{\rm CM} $$

and for the rotational motion (balance torques at center of mass, positive is CCW)

$$ -x\,N - \tfrac{h}{2} \mu N = I_{\rm CM} (-  \ddot \alpha) $$

where $I_{\rm CM}$ is the mass moment of inertia about the center of mass, and $h$ is the thickness of the bar.

The above three equations are to be solved for the three unknowns, $\ddot x$, $\ddot \alpha$ and $N$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the torque acting on the system. A normal force that is off-center will cause rotation in your drawing.

$\mathbf{N} \times \ldots$ is the torque due to the normal force.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The object would rotate about the point of contact, you can easily find the angular acceleration of the bar, about the point of contact , about this point of contact the only torque would be due to $\cfrac{Mgx}{\cos \theta}$,

if you find the angular acceleration, you can find the vertical acceleration of center of mass of the bar by multiplying angular acceleration with $\cfrac{x}{\cos\theta}$ and it would be downwards.

Then as you know the vertical acceleration of center of mass of the bar, you could easily add out all the  forces in the system in vertical direction like vectors and equate it with vertical acceleration of the bar and get the required normal force.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand few things though: why does the torque equal mgx/cos(a)? Shouldn't it be mgx*cos(a)? And why multiplying by x/cos(a) gives me vertical acceleration?

Comment: multiplying $x/\cos\theta$ with angular acceleration would give you acceleration of the center of mass point which is in vertical direction perpendicular to $x/\cos\theta$

Comment: @FrankCold actually if you look from distance $x$ , you will be getting torque as $mgx\cos\theta$, but the other component of force of Mg i.e $mg\sin\theta$ would also exert torque from distance $x/\cos\theta$

Comment: you will get $x/\cos\theta$ distance by drawing a horizontal line from point of contact to center of mass of the bar, for calculating torque you need resultant force at that point, i hope you know this

Comment: yeah, I get it. Forgot to mention: I wanted to assume that upper body has negligible thickness so we wouldnt have to worry about sin component of the force.

Comment: but now i get it, thanks.

Comment: @FrankCold You can thank me by clicking on the tick mark..

Comment: I did, but have less than 15 reputation. Sorry.